# Diretiva Alias - O que seria?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Boa tarde pessoal,

Ando estudando C#, cheguei a ver sobre a Diretiva using, e na documentação do C# diz possuir 3 usos, um dos 3 itens de uso diz que serve para criar um “alias” para um namespace ou um tipo, mas o que seria uma diretiva alias e qual sua utilidade? Pesquisei e não encontrei sobre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serve para evitar ambiguidade. Imagine a seguinte situação:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;  
using System.Windows.Input;
```

Nestes dois `namespaces` há classes em comuns. Como o compilador saberia qual classe você quer? Para resolver isto e ainda usar o `using` você pode criar um apelido (`alias`):

```
using Input = System.Windows.Input;
```

Assim, você poderia acessar, por exemplo: `Input.ModifierKeys`não gerando nenhuma ambiguidade pois ele sabe que `Input` refere-se a `System.Windows.Input`.

Alguns também acreditam que possa ser uma boa prática, isto eu já não sei responder corretamente.

> Esta resposta foi baseada na resposta de Zv_oDD em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505262/c-sharp-namespace-alias-whats-the-point (SOen)

Comment: Eu ainda nao entendi para que serve "alias", existe um exemplo mais didatico?

Comment: Tambem ainda nao entendi?